# How to import module installed using pip from virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I installed virtual env, activated it, installed packages I want but when it came to import those packages in jupyter notebook I am wrecking my brain for a good while now.

```
(cntk) C:\Users\sushant>pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
cntk       2.6
numpy      1.15.4
pip        18.1
scipy      1.1.0
setuptools 40.6.3
wheel      0.32.3
```

how do I import cntk from virtaul env (cntk) to jupyter notebook.
I tried

```
from C:\Users\sushant\cntk\Lib\site-packages\cntk import cntk
```

but apparently is not the way to do it  its giving me `invalid syntex`

**Update**

I have learnt that Virtual environments are not cross-importable which is what I was trying to do.

Comment: just use `import cntk` or `from cntk.train import Trainer, minibatch_size_schedule` read the samples https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/v2.6/Examples

Comment: Python `import` is different from C/C++ `#include` so paths are not needed as long as properly installed.

Comment: Using just `import cntk` gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cntk'` I think its searching that module in general environment while its installed in another environment

Comment: if you are not already doing this. install jupyter notebook to the environment and use it. don't try to use jupyter from somewhere else.

Comment: @Bhathiya Perera What if I want to import package which is not in that same environment

Comment: You cannot and you shouldn't. you need to have things in the virtual environment. venv is created so you can work on multiple projects without polluting global packages. so obviously you will need to reinstall stuff to virtual environment that you need to use it in.

Comment: @SushantKarande *What if I want to import package which is not in that same environment* Install it into the current environment. Virtual environments are not cross-importable. You can manipulate `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` but I predict problems on the way.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have installed jupyter notebook kernel as you meant.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
from.your_packagename.sub_package import class_name
```

by this you can access class and sub packages of that package

Comment: I know how to import package the problem is I have installed package in another environment